# Build a WPF application in VScode gave me error MSB4062

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I am trying to perform a build on a WPF (.Net Core 3.1) in Visual Studio Code (not Visual Studio this time cause I need a more lightweight editor).Normally all my project can be built fine, but this WPF project gave me this following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.
WinFX.targets(225,9): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Windows.MarkupCompilePass1" task could not be loaded from
 the assembly C:\Program Files %28x86%29\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\tools\netcoreapp2.1\PresentationBuildTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files 
%28x86%29\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\tools\netcoreapp2.1\PresentationBuildTasks.dll'. The system cannot find the path specified.
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all 
its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that 
implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [E:\ui_wpf_test\ui_wpf_test.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

I heard that it has to do with MSbuild, but I dont know how to correctly fix this

Comment: Seems like the `PresentationBuildTasks.dll` was not found. Is this a part of an SDK? Do you have that SKD installed?

Comment: Yes, the `PresentationBuildTasks.dll` was there in the correct location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2415#issuecomment-580458290). You have to replace the following line of `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFx.props`:

```
<_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly Condition="'$(_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly)'==''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\$(_PresentationBuildTasksTfm)\PresentationBuildTasks.dll'))</_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly>
```

Replace it with:

```
<_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly Condition="'$(_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly)'==''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\$(_PresentationBuildTasksTfm)\PresentationBuildTasks.dll</_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly>
```

This has eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

small bug. should be fixed in the new upcoming 3.1.103 instead of now 3.1.102.

Problem is the path `Program Files (x86)' where`(x86)`is escaped to`%28x86%29`, resulting in path not found.

temporary fix by just escaping the path:

Go to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets

edit Microsoft.WinFx.props and use this _PresentationBuildTaskAssembly which has the Unescape for the path:

```
    <_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly Condition="'$(_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly)'==''">$([MSBuild]::Unescape($([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\$(_PresentationBuildTasksTfm)\PresentationBuildTasks.dll'))))</_PresentationBuildTasksAssembly>
```

It is possible that you can resolve it also by changing in visual studio the build to x64 instead of Any CPU/x86. With 64-bit this will use `C:\Program Files\` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and thus not have the 'bad' characters.